# Why does my Raspberry Pi 4 model B keep disconnecting from the Internet?

Tags: pi-4

I have been using my raspberry pi to learn how to program games with python, and I have loved it so far... but there is one problem. Every so often, it will disconnect from my WiFi and will not reconnect. Rebooting, shutting down, or editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, as I have found fixed the problem for some people, will not fix it. When I hover over the symbol in the top panel where the WiFi options are, it says:

```
wlan0: Disassociated from (my WiFi name).  
eth0: link is down
```

Can you help me with this?

EDIT: I’m sorry if I was not as descriptive as I needed to be... I’ll make sure to be more descriptive next time I ask a question.
So, the main problem is, I do not know what fixes it. I just got on it right now, a day after I asked this question, and it was connected to WiFi. It then disconnected for a little bit, but eventually reconnected again. It finally disconnected a final time and will now not reconnect.
While trying to find an answer to my problem, many questions I found involve different models of the raspberry pi that require an Ethernet cable to use WiFi. Because I have a Raspberry Pi 4, it is supposed to connect to WiFi wirelessly.
One thing that I forgot to mention (I’m sorry), was that I seemed to be having these problems with the WiFi after I learned how to use VNC on it, so I can use my iPad as a monitor. I’m not sure if this it’s the reason why it is disconnecting, as it is still is disconnecting when I have VNC disabled on the pi. 
I do not think that it is a problem with my WiFi because all of my other devices seem to be connecting fine.
Also, when I am connected to WiFi, it still says

eth0: link is down

Hopefully these details will help, sorry I wasn’t as descriptive earlier!

Comment: so rebooting doesn't fix it? what does? because you didn't say that it no longer connects, so obviously it does reconnect

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't in your WiFi Access Point/Route?

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. -- In this case, there is plenty of possibilities. You should search out and do something then add the detail/result of the problem here.

Comment: What power supply are you using? This may be due to it receiving inadequate power. Have you tried connecting it through Ethernet?

Comment: You have answered your question with an **EDIT:**. Please don't answer the question in the question. Just cut this paragraph and paste it into an answer. There is nothing wrong to answer the own question. Then after two days please accept the answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.